# Search operation in a linked list using c++

Tags: c++, c, linked-list

I have a linked list implemented in c++, which I want to search just after inserting data values. The record to be searched is prompted from the user.However, the search function does not work as expected, it keeps returning "No match found". What could be the problem?

```
struct node{
    char name[60];
    char admission[10];
    char grade;
    node *next;
};

node* search(node* head){
    node *temp=head;
    char name[60];
    cout << "Enter Student to search :";
    cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
    cin.getline(name, 60);
    cout << name;
        while (temp!=NULL){
            if(strcmp(temp->name, name)==0){
                cout << "Match found";
                return temp;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        cout << "No match found";
        return NULL;
}

int main(){
    node *head = NULL;

    char name[60];
    char admission[10];
    char grade;

    node *temp;
    temp = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
    int i=0;

    while(i<2){
        cout << "Enter students name: ";
        cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
        cin.getline(name, 60);
        cout << "Enter student's admission number: ";
        cin.getline(admission, 10);
        cout << "Enter student's grade :";
        cin >> grade;
        strcpy(temp->name, name);
        strcpy(temp->admission,admission);
        temp->grade = grade;
        head = temp;
        i++;
    }
    search(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Apart from the I/O this is mostly C, not C++ - is that what you actually intended ?

Comment: your insert isnt right.

Comment: Yes, everything works well apart from the search() operation.

Comment: Your insert function just replaces the one element in there.. You never have more than 1 element.

Comment: Karthik T, How should the insert be then?

Comment: The insert is most definitely not correct, every time you do "head = temp;" therefore your list is only the last element created.

Comment: @user1289167 No. You only create one element, it is even *before* the while loop!

Comment: Thanks for the correction people. How should the insert be done then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your insert code ensures that your list has only one node. The data of that node will be overwritten to store the last data entered. This is why your search operation would fail.

What your insert needs to be doing is:

1. Allocate memory for a node.
2. Initialize all it's members and make sure to set the `next` pointer to NULL! Doing so will avoid invoking undefined behavior when you least expect it.
3. Make this allocated node your head node.
4. Have a temporary node pointer, say `temp`, which points to the head node. **DO NOT allocate memory for this node**. Doing so = memory leak.
5. Allocate memory for another node.
6. Populate that node's data and **initialize the `next` pointer to NULL**.
7. Make `temp->next` point to the node allocated in step 5.
8. Move `temp` to the node allocated in step 5 (by `temp = temp->next`).
9. Go to step 5 if you want more nodes. Otherwise, continue to your search.

Make sure you free the memory you allocated for each node because if you ever use this code as a module in some larger code-base, you'd have a memory leak.

Also, as the other answers have pointed out, your `strcpy` usage is wrong. Basically, the syntax is:

```
strcpy(destination, source);
```

I suggest you read the [manual for `strcpy`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/strcpy.html) for a clearer understanding.

Additionally, why not use `new` instead of `malloc`?

Answer (score 2):

You copy the names the wrong way:

```
strcpy(name, temp->name);
```

should be

```
strcpy(temp->name, name);
```

Destination goed first: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

A good way for debugging this, is to print all the comparisons you do.

(Also, I reckon this is learning code and not production code, as it is full of buffer overflow bugs.)

Comment: +1 missed that. He also only allocates a single node for the whole loop and overwrites it.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson that's true as well.

Comment: I edited the code following the correction you gave above. Please direct me to the other mistakes in my code...I'm a noob in C++ :)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

#define NAME_SIZE 60
#define ADMI_SIZE 10

struct node{
    char name[NAME_SIZE];
    char admission[ADMI_SIZE];
    char grade;
    node *next;
};

node* search(node* head){
    node *temp=head;
    char name[NAME_SIZE];
    cout << "Enter Student to search :";
    cin.getline(name, NAME_SIZE);
    cout << name;
    while (temp!=NULL){
        if(strcmp(temp->name, name)==0){
            cout << " Match found";
            return temp;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout << " No match found";
    return NULL;
}

void drop(node* n){
    if(n == NULL) return;
    drop(n->next);
    delete n;
}

int main(){
    node *head = NULL;

    char name[NAME_SIZE];
    char admission[ADMI_SIZE];
    char grade;

    int i=0;

    while(i<2){
        cout << "Enter students name: ";
        cin.getline(name, 60);
        cout << "Enter student's admission number: ";
        cin.getline(admission, 10);
        cout << "Enter student's grade :";
        cin >> grade;
        cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
        node *temp = new node;
        strcpy(temp->name, name);
        strcpy(temp->admission,admission);
        temp->grade = grade;
        temp->next = head;
        head = temp;
        i++;
    }
    search(head);
    drop(head);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

strcpy seems to be reveresed.

It should be 
strcpy(temp->name, name);
strcpy(temp->admission, admission);

Also program might end in crashing as temp->next = NULL; is not performed.